# What was the recipe for making books before 1.3.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What was the recipe for making books in Minecraft before update 1.3.1?

Comment: Please state if you are talking about PC, Xbox, or PE minecraft.

Comment: the PC minecraft

Comment: Couldn't you have just googled that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Three paper in a vertical line.

[image]

Comment: Ah, those were the days....

Comment: Cows hated the 1.3.1 update